# Filtered const_iterator operator++(int)

Tags: c++, iterator, operators

I'd like to ask if this is a correct implementation of const iterator operator++(int)?

```
const_iterator operator++(int) {
   const_iterator previous(pointer,end,filter);
   while(pointer!=end_){
         pointer++;
         if(filter(*pointer)) return previous;
   }
        return const_iterator(end,end,filter);
}
```

pointer- pointer to current element, end- pointer to end, and filter- filter function

Comment: If you think actually seeing the definition of the iterator classes would be at-least-marginally helpful, you couldn't be more right.

Answer (score 2):

You should return `previous` whether or not you reach the end.

It might make sense to implement this in terms of pre-increment:

```
const_iterator previous(*this);
++(*this);
return previous;
```